# Returning None or a tuple and unpacking

Tags: python, return-value

I am always annoyed by this fact:

```
$ cat foo.py
def foo(flag):
    if flag:
        return (1,2)
    else:
        return None

first, second = foo(True)
first, second = foo(False)

$ python foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    first, second = foo(False)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The fact is that in order to correctly unpack without troubles I have either to catch the TypeError or to have something like

```
values = foo(False)
if values is not None:
    first, second = values
```

Which is kind of annoying. Is there a trick to improve this situation (e.g. to so set both first and second to None without having foo returning (None, None)) or a suggestion about the best design strategy for cases like the one I present ? *variables maybe ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, you could do...

```
first,second = foo(True) or (None,None)
first,second = foo(False) or (None,None)
```

but as far as I know there's no simpler way to expand None to fill in the entirety of a tuple.

Comment: ooooh... this I didn't consider. very "perlish" approach, but clever.

Comment: I disagree about it being perl-ish.  `x or y` is a very pythonic way of saying `(x ? x : y)` or `(if x then x else y)` or `(if not x then y)` or however else you want to explain it.

Comment: ok, just worked out of a "sing along" the "whatever or die()" typical perl phrase.

Comment: Generally I don't like this syntax because of the danger of unexpected False-y values, but in this case it's okay.

Answer (score 34):

I don't see what is wrong with returning (None,None). It is much cleaner than the solutions suggested here which involve far more changes in your code.

It also doesn't make sense that you want None to automagically be split into 2 variables.

Comment: I was just in the process of thinking the same. I agree that it does not make sense: from the conceptual point of view, returning None w.r.t. a tuple of Nones is probably different (of course it depends on the real routine. Here we are talking mock cases)

Comment: +1 -- absolutely -- it's weird to make the function return such an whacko mix of results and have to deal with it in the caller.

Comment: @Alex: well, that depends. In general, you can have cases of routines that are supposed to return _x_ (with x = whatever) or None if not found. If you know that x is a tuple, and a tuple of two objects, it's a special case, but the case _x_ or None if not found is still valid. The fact that you unpack it is oblivious to the called routine.

Comment: But then you should treat the return value as a whole - the fact it is a tuple that you can easily unpack is just coincidental.

Comment: Sometimes the two values are tied together, *always*. Consider @rob's discussion below. It's a bit ridiculous to write `(None, None)` for a nonexistent point2d. Also, what does `(None, 3)` mean when talking about point2ds? Nothing. So why not call it a `None` and be done with?

Comment: @Stefano. What are exceptions for?

Answer (score 23):

I think there is a problem of **abstraction**.

A function should maintain some level of abstraction, that helps in reducing complexity of the code.
In this case, either the function is not maintaining the right abstraction, either the caller is not respecting it.

The function could have been something like `get_point2d()`; in this case, the level of the abstraction is on the tuple, and therefore returning None would be a good way to signal some particular case (e.g. non-existing entity). The error in this case would be to expect two items, while actually the only thing you know is that the function returns one object (with information related to a 2d point).

But it could also have been something like `get_two_values_from_db()`; in this case the abstraction would be broken by returning None, because the function (as the name suggest) *should return two values and not one*!

Either way, the main goal of using a function - reducing complexity - is, at least partially, lost.

Note that this issue would not appear clearly with the original name; that's also why it is always important to give good names to function and methods.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there's a trick. You can simplify your calling code to:

```
values = foo(False)
if values:
    first, second = values
```

or even:

```
values = foo(False)
first, second = values or (first_default, second_default)
```

where first_default and second_default are values you'd give to first and second as defaults.

Comment: Which python version is the second option working?
v = (1,); 
x, y = v or (v, 2)

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful with the `x or y` style of solution.  They work, but they're a bit broader than your original specification.  Essentially, what if `foo(True)` returns an empty tuple `()`?  As long as you know that it's OK to treat that as `(None, None)`, you're good with the solutions provided.

If this were a common scenario, I'd probably write a utility function like:

```
# needs a better name! :)
def to_tup(t):
    return t if t is not None else (None, None)

first, second = to_tup(foo(True))
first, second = to_tup(foo(False))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$ cat foo.py 
def foo(flag):
    if flag:
        return (1,2)
    else:
        return (None,)*2

first, second = foo(True)
first, second = foo(False)
```

**Edit:** Just to be clear, the only change is to replace `return None` with `return (None,)*2`.  I am extremely surprised that no one else has thought of this.  (Or if they have, I would like to know why they didn't use it.)

Comment: Because the OP explicitly said "without having foo returning (None, None)". `return (None,)*2` is the same as `return (None,None)`.

Comment: Are you sure that's what was meant?  I thought the OP just wanted to avoid *typing* the longish expression `return None, None` all the time.  My way solves that problem.

Comment: Well, it doesn't solve it completely of course, but does reduce it, and works ever better for longer tuples of a given size.

Answer (score 2):

Over 10 years later, if you want to use default values I don't think there is a better way than the one already provided:

```
first, second = foo(False) or (first_default, second_default)
```

However, if you want to skip the case when `None` is returned, starting from Python 3.8 you can use the **walrus operator** (ie. [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)) - also note the simplified `foo`:

```
def foo(flag):
    return (1, 2) if flag else None

if values := Foo(False):
    (first, second) = values
```

You could use an `else` branch to assign default values that's worse than the previous `or` option.

Sadly, the walrus operator [does not support unparenthesized tuples](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#allowing-commas-to-the-right) so it is just a one line gain compared to:

```
values = foo(False)
if values:
    first, second = values
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I would just return (None, None), but as long as we are in whacko-land (heh), here is a way using a subclass of tuple.  In the else case, you don't return None, but instead return an empty container, which seems to be in the spirit of things.  The container's "iterator" unpacks None values when empty.  Demonstrates the iterator protocol anyway...

Tested using v2.5.2:

```
class Tuple(tuple):
    def __iter__(self):
        if self:
            # If Tuple has contents, return normal tuple iterator...
            return super(Tuple, self).__iter__()
        else:
            # Else return a bogus iterator that returns None twice...
            class Nonerizer(object):
                def __init__(self):
                    self.x=0
                def __iter__(self):
                    return self
                def next(self):
                    if self.x < 2:
                        self.x += 1
                        return None
                    else:
                        raise StopIteration
            return Nonerizer()


def foo(flag):
    if flag:
        return Tuple((1,2))
    else:
        return Tuple()  # It's not None, but it's an empty container.

first, second = foo(True)
print first, second
first, second = foo(False)
print first, second
```

Output is the desired:

```
1 2
None None
```

Comment: `Nonerizer()` can be replaced with `itertools.repeat(None, 2)`.

Comment: @augurar or just `iter((None, None))`, making the whole exercise pointless.

Answer (score 1):

One mechanism you can use to avoid the problem entirely when you have control of the method foo is to change the prototype to allow giving a default.  This works if you are wrapping state but can't guarantee that a particular tuple value exists.

```
# self.r is for example, a redis cache

# This method is like foo - 
# it has trouble when you unpack a json serialized tuple
def __getitem__(self, key):
    val = self.r.get(key)
    if val is None:
        return None
    return json.loads(val)

# But this method allows the caller to 
# specify their own default value whether it be
# (None, None) or an entire object
def get(self, key, default):
    val = self.r.get(key)
    if val is None:
        return default
    return json.loads(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(flag):
    return ((1,2) if flag else (None, None))
```

Comment: This is not really the core of the question.

Comment: The question says " e.g. to so set both first and second to None without having foo returning (None, None)", or are you saying that there's nothing wrong with returning `(None, None)`?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance (1) If multiple paths in a function return values, I prefer that they all have the same shape, for some of the exact reasons the poster raises. (2) My answer is from 14 years ago. It's entirely possible that the text was edited after my answer was submitted.

Comment: 1) Sure. Somebody for some reason (incorrectly) flagged this with the Not an Answer flag, so it just ended up in review. I just leave comments so people don't review to delete it carelessly. 2) The question wasn't changed, and I think your explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem:

Return None or return an object.

However you don't want to have to write a class just to return an object. For this, you can use a **named tuple**

Like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
def foo(flag):
if flag:
   return None
else:
    MyResult = namedtuple('MyResult',['a','b','c']
    return MyResult._make([1,2,3])
```

And then:

```
result = foo(True) # result = True
result = foo(False) # result = MyResult(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

And you have access to the results like this:

```
print result.a # 1
print result.b # 2
print result.c # 3
```