# update matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to update a matplotlib plot as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdate
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i,(_,_,idx) in enumerate(local_minima):
    dat = dst_data[idx-24:idx+25]
    dates,values = zip(*dat)
    if i == 0:
        assert(len(dates) == len(values))
        lines2d, = ax.plot_date(mdate.date2num(dates), np.array(values), linestyle='-')
    else:
        assert(len(dates) == len(values))
        lines2d.set_ydata(np.array(values))
        lines2d.set_xdata(mdate.date2num(dates))  #This line causes problems.

        fig.canvas.draw()
    raw_input()
```

The first time through the loop, the plot displays just fine.  The second time through the loop, all of the data on my plot disappears -- everything works fine if I don't include the `lines2d.set_xdata` line (other than the x-data points being wrong of course).  I've looked at the following posts:

[How to update a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/matplotlib-update-a-plot)

and

[Update Lines in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371255/update-lines-in-matplotlib)

However, in both cases, the user is only updating the `ydata` and I would like to update the `xdata` as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As is the typical case, the act of writing up a question inspired me to look into a possibility I hadn't thought of previously.  The x-data *is* being updated, but the plot ranges are not.  When I put new data on the plot, it was all out of range.  The solution was to add:

```
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
```

[(partial reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215060/748858)

---

Here's the code in context of the original question in hopes that it will be helpful to someone else someday:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdate
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i,(_,_,idx) in enumerate(local_minima):
    dat = dst_data[idx-24:idx+25]
    dates,values = zip(*dat)
    if i == 0:
        assert(len(dates) == len(values))
        lines2d, = ax.plot_date(mdate.date2num(dates), np.array(values), linestyle='-')
    else:
        assert(len(dates) == len(values))
        lines2d.set_ydata(np.array(values))
        lines2d.set_xdata(mdate.date2num(dates))  #This line causes problems.
        ax.relim()
        ax.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
        fig.canvas.draw()
    raw_input()
```