# unable to eliminate 'NoneType' object is not iterable error in DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm an old SAS user new to Python. SO has several examples of why this error occurs.  
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-in-python) for example.

I want to eliminate this source of error.  I'm working with a large dataframe created with the read_cvs reader.

```
print(df.size, df.shape, df.ndim)
7202952 (266776, 27) 2
```

Date and Time are objects:

```
print(df.Date.dtype)
print(df.Time.dtype)
object
object
```

So I convert them to datetime:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

Set df.Date as the index:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Drop na's:

```
df = df.dropna()
print(df.shape)
(266752, 26)
```

And verify there are 24 fewer rows than indicated above:

Count the number of accident reports on Dec. 25, 2015 with:

```
print(len(df.loc['2015-07-04']))
625
```

Good so far. Now count the number of accident reports between Dec. 25, 2015 and Dec 31, 2015 with:

```
print(len(df.loc[['2015-12-25','2015-12-26']]))
```

which returns:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I've run out of ideas, so I check the index with:

```
print(df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-09', '2015-01-09', '2015-02-23', '2015-02-23',
           '2015-02-23', '2015-02-11', '2015-02-11', '2015-02-23',
           '2015-02-23', '2015-04-18',
           ...
           '2015-08-30', '2015-11-29', '2015-11-29', '2015-11-29',
           '2015-07-26', '2015-07-26', '2015-12-31', '2015-07-28',
           '2015-07-28', '2015-07-15'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=266752, freq=None)
```

I would like to understand what is the source of this error.  Other thoughts are: perhaps sorting df.Date would help, given Date is 'out-of-order' and with multiple rows for each day.

I assumed that dropping the 24 rows would solve the problem.  And I also assume that since the DataFrame contains no objects, I would not have any None objects.

```
df.get_dtype_counts()
datetime64[ns]     1
int64             25
dtype: int64
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: The dates in your code examples don't seem to be consistent with your explanatory text.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with my dataset, but found that when I used pandas.to_datetime to convert the dates I was selecting with, it worked. Here's some example code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=pd.date_range(start='2015-01-01', periods=6, freq='D'), columns=list('ABCD'))
len(df1.loc[['2015-01-01', '2015-01-03'],:])
```

returns an error

```
len(df1.loc[pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-03']),:])
```

returns 2