# BeautifulSoup : Why is the "dlink_find('a')['href']" not working?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a script to download subtitles from one specific website. Please read the comments in the code.
Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

count = 0
usearch = input("Movie Name? : ")
search_url = "https://www.yifysubtitles.com/search?q="+usearch
base_url = "https://www.yifysubtitles.com"
print(search_url)
resp = requests.get(search_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all("div",{"class": "media-body"}):       #Get the exact class:'media-body'
    imdb = link.find('a')['href']                               #Find the link in that class, which is the exact link we want
    movie_url = base_url+imdb                                   #Merge the result with base string to navigate to the movie page
    print("Movie URL : {}".format(movie_url))                   #Print the URL just to check.. :p

    next_page = requests.get(movie_url)                         #Soup number 2 begins here, after navigating to the movie page
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(next_page.content,'lxml')
    #print(soup2.prettify())
    for links in soup2.find_all("tr",{"class": "high-rating"}): #Navigate to subtitle options with class as high-rating
        for flags in links.find("td", {"class": "flag-cell"}):  #Look for all the flags of subtitles with high-ratings
            if flags.text == "English":                         #If flag is set to English then get the download link
                print("After if : {}".format(links))
                for dlink in links.find("td",{"class": "download-cell"}):   #Once English check is done, navigate to the download class "download-cell" where the download href exists
                    half_dlink = dlink.find('a')['href']                    #STUCK HERE!!!HERE'S THE PROBLEM!!! SOS!!! HELP!!!
                    download = base_url + half_dlink
                    print(download)
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
 File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/WhatsApp_API/SubtitleDownloader.py", line 24, in <module>
    for x in dlink.find("a"):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You should build some fallbacks: what if there is no English subtitle, or no subtitle with the highest rating. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-in-python

Comment: I checked out your link, but the thing is "dlink.find('a')['href'], should return a download link to a movies subtitle. And as for the fallbacks, once I get this script working properly in it's rudimentary form, I'll modify it. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Did you try changing the above line this `for dlink in links.find("td",{"class": "download-cell"}):` to this `for dlink in links.find_all("td",{"class": "download-cell"}):`

Comment: @Abdullah Ahmed Ghaznavi Thanks! It worked. But what's the difference between "find()" and "find_all()" methods in the context of my code?

Comment: welcome! :) The only difference is that `find_all()` returns a list containing the single result, and `find()` just returns the result. and in your case you are running a loop on a single element rather than a list

Comment: And it works so i will make a answer of it so that it might help others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the above line this:

`for dlink in links.find("td",{"class": "download-cell"}):`

to this:

```
for dlink in links.find_all("td",{"class": "download-cell"}):
```

because you are running a loop on an single element rather than a list.

**Note:** The only difference is that find_all() returns a list containing the single result, and find() just returns the result.

Hope this will helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) and [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find).

> `find_all()`:
>
> > The `find_all()` method looks through a tag’s descendants and retrieves *all* descendants that match your filters.
>
> `find`:
>
> > The `find_all()` method scans the entire document looking for results, but sometimes you only want to find one result. If you know a
> >     document only has one `<body>` tag, it’s a waste of time to scan the
> >     entire document looking for more. Rather than passing in `limit=1`
> >     every time you call `find_all`, you can use the `find()` method.

So, you don't need to loop over the `find()` function to get the tags. You need to make the following changes in your code (removed the unnecessary `for` loops):

```
...
# Previous code is the same

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(next_page.content,'lxml')
for links in soup2.find_all("tr",{"class": "high-rating"}):
    if links.find("td", {"class": "flag-cell"}).text == "English":
        print("After if : {}".format(links))
        half_dlink = links.find('td', {'class': 'download-cell'}).a['href']
        download = base_url + half_dlink
        print(download)
```

Comment: Thanks for the python documentation snippet!