# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable when using zip_longest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am developing a python script to analyse a txt file and then save it to a osv file. I am trying to use "zip_longest" from the module "itertools". When one of my dictionaries no longer has i value i want it to paste a empty space while the other dictionary continues to paste its values.
My code looks like this:

```
def csvExport(self):
        exportYN = input("Would you like to export the document to a CSV file? (Y/N):")
        if (exportYN == "Y" or exportYN == "y"):
            with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
                csvfile.write("Username;Repeated;Password;Repeated")
                for (username, usrValue), (password, passValue) in itertools.zip_longest(self.usernames.items(), self.passwords.items()):
                    csvfile.write(str(username) + ";" + str(usrValue) + ";" + str(password) + ";" + str(passValue))
```

And the error code looks like this:

```
for (username, usrValue), (password, passValue) in itertools.zip_longest(self.usernames.items(), self.passwords.items()):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I think it is related to zip_longest because the two dictionaries i use is not the same length.

Hope you can help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-in-python)

Comment: Dictionaries don't guarantee order (although as of Python 3.6 input order is preserved); depending on how those dictionaries are generated, there is a possibility you are not going to get the output order you want.

Comment: And the `NoneType` error stems from trying to unpack `None` into two variables, either `username, usrValue = None` or `password, passValue = None`. Think about what kind of default value instead of `None` would be a fit for that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `fillvalue` keyword argument of `zip_longest`:

```
ziplongest(..., ..., fillvalue=('', ''))
```

Otherwise the default is `None` and `None` cannot fill a 2-tuple for example `(username, usrValue)`.

Aside from that, since dictionaries are not ordered the `zip` operation will return random pairs...