# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable adding layers in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I was trying to run the following code for creating a network in keras:

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

num_classes=len(np.unique(y_train))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 10
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
```

but I receive the following error message

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

here it is the full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../filename.py", line 31, in <module>
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 166, in add
    layer(x)
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 463, in __call__
    self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 137, in build
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=kernel_shape,
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 279, in add_weight
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape, dtype=dtype),
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 226, in __call__
    x = K.random_uniform(shape, -limit, limit,
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 4356, in random_uniform
    return tf_keras_backend.random_uniform(
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 5685, in random_uniform
    return random_ops.random_uniform(
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\random_ops.py", line 282, in random_uniform
    shape = tensor_util.shape_tensor(shape)
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 1015, in shape_tensor
    return ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtype, name="shape")
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1341, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 321, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 261, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 270, in _constant_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 95, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    ctx.ensure_initialized()
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 502, in ensure_initialized
    config_str = self.config.SerializeToString()
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 880, in config
    self._initialize_physical_devices()
  File "...\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 1167, in _initialize_physical_devices
    self._physical_devices = [
```

For what I can understand, looking at the Tracebabk, the problem is in the file `context.py` at line 1166:
`devs = pywrap_tfe.TF_ListPhysicalDevices()`
devs is <class 'NoneType'> then at the following line
`self._physical_devices = [PhysicalDevice(name=d.decode(),device_type=d.decode().split(":")[1]) for d in devs]`
when it tries to iterate on it, it obviously raises the TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

For some reason the list of physical devices is empty, but the function `TF_ListPhysicalDevices()` does not yield and empty list but a None.

Anyway even if I set `self._physical_devices` to an empty list, it will then raise another error elsewhere (`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: No CPU devices are available in this process`)

Any idea on how I can solve this. Thank you.

I have copied the code I was trying to run from the webpage https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-deep-learning-project-handwritten-digit-recognition

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I have added the full error traceback. Thank you

Comment: Ok, but you seem to be missing the bottom where it names the error and the line number that causes it.

Comment: the error is TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Yes, but I can’t tell which line it occurred on and which variable is involved.

Comment: at the bottom it doesn't say anything else. The line causing the error is ```model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))```

Comment: Hello I have added  few more details to my question. I hope it helps clarifying a little bit the problem. If you can help with it I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you are trying to iterate over a `None` value (i.e. the variable has no value).
You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-in-python) a similar post.

With the stacktrace you should be able to identify the source of the error and fix it, but as long as you don't provide it, we can't help you.

Here I don't see any loop in your code, which means that the error probably comes from an another method for which you passed an argument with `None` type.

Comment: Hello I have added the error Traceback and few more details to my question. I hope it helps clarifying a little bit the problem. If you can help with it I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of keras. This issue is not there with `2.3.1`.

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

num_classes=len(np.unique(y_train))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 10
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
print("seems fine")
```

gives

```
(60000, 28, 28) (60000,)
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
seems fine
```

Comment: I do have the ```2.3.1``` version of keras