# How to install easy OCR

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install this

```
https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR
```

I have tried installing using pip install easyocr but I keep getting this error

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting easyocr
  Using cached easyocr-1.0.tar.gz (8.5 MB)
Collecting torch
  Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
Collecting torchvision
  Using cached torchvision-0.2.2.post3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.3.0.38.tar.gz (88.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\python.exe' 'c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'c:\users\fatima~1.ars\appdata\local\temp\tmp_bwb7g'
       cwd: c:\users\fatima~1.ars\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-hccohn\opencv-python
  Complete output (22 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "c:\users\fatima~1.ars\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-xcaozb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "c:\users\fatima~1.ars\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-xcaozb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "c:\users\fatima~1.ars\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-xcaozb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 243, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "c:\users\fatima~1.ars\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-xcaozb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 448, in <module>
      main()
    File "setup.py", line 99, in main
      % {"ext": re.escape(sysconfig.get_config_var("EXT_SUFFIX"))}
    File "c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\re.py", line 210, in escape
      s = list(pattern)
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\python.exe' 'c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'c:\users\fatima~1.ars\appdata\local\temp\tmp_bwb7g' Check
```

the logs for full command output.

Not really sure what the error is about. If I install using the second command it simply says that pytorch doesnt satisfy requirement. I installed pytorch but still same issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 2.7 installing opencv via pip (virtual environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346648/python-2-7-installing-opencv-via-pip-virtual-environment)

Comment: @DavidBuck now it is giving this problem Running setup.py install for torch ... error

Comment: Simple question is do you have to do this on Python 2.7? Now it is a year past its End of Life so lots of packages have withdrawn support altogether. If you insist on using Python 2.7, you'll have to make sure you're specifying compatible versions of each package you use.

Comment: Well my base environment is on 2.7. my env is 3.6. How do I upgrade?

Comment: If you have Python 3.6 installed, you're currently working in the wrong environment. Python 2.7 isn't a 'base' environment (i.e. it's not needed to run Python 3.6). There's loads of articles on the internet about setting up a Python environment ([this](https://realpython.com/installing-python/) for example), or how to use a virtual environment ([this](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) for example). A lot of it will depend of your operating system, experience, etc. so I can only suggest by doing some reading, so you can make sure you're using the environment you want

Comment: @DavidBuck 'base' is just the name of the standard env that you get with an anaconda installation. It is also not neccessary (and only confusing) to use virtualenv when OP is already using conda

Answer (score 4):

You have an outdated python version in your base environment.  This is not necessarily a problem (but you still might want to consider installing an anaconda3/miniconda3 version instead), since you can just create a new environment with a newer python version:

Create new env and activate it:

```
conda create -n easyocr python=3.8
conda activate easyocr
```

Install PyTorch (get the correct command depending on your CUDA version from [here](https://pytorch.org/)):

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

Then you should be able to run:

```
pip install easyocr
```