# Tuple Concept : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Code :

```
input_tuple = ('Monty Python', 'British', 1969)
y = list(input_tuple)
z = y.append("Python")
tuple_2 = tuple(z)
print(tuple_2)
```

**expected o/p**:

```
('Monty Python', 'British', 1969, 'Python')
```

**But getting as** :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-037856922f23> in <module>
      3 y = list(input_tuple)
      4 z = y.append("Python")
----> 5 tuple_2 = tuple(z)
      6 # Make sure to name the final tuple 'tuple_2'
      7 print(tuple_2)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Did you check this out ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-in-python

Comment: What are you expecting `z` to be? `y.append` doesn't have any output so `z` will always be None, which causes your error.

Comment: Replace `z = y.append("Python")` with `z = y + ["Python"]`

Answer (score 2):

that's not how append works. you do not need to save y.append value in z it will directly updated in y, so create tuple of modified y

look at this, this works as you wnats..

```
input_tuple = ('Monty Python', 'British', 1969)
y = list(input_tuple)
y.append("Python")
tuple_2 = tuple(y)
print(tuple_2)
```