# TypeError at /admin/login/ 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

```
TypeError at /admin/login/
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 4.1.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Exception Location: E:\mohammad\Dijongo\myprojects\Greany\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\templates\panel.py, line 47, in _request_context_bind_template
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.sites.login
Python Executable:  E:\mohammad\Dijongo\myprojects\Greany\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.1
Python Path:    
['E:\\mohammad\\Dijongo\\myprojects\\Greany\\src',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310',
 'E:\\mohammad\\Dijongo\\myprojects\\Greany',
 'E:\\mohammad\\Dijongo\\myprojects\\Greany\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 22 Nov 2022 17:41:41 +0000
```

project repo: https://github.com/pythone-developer/Ecomerce-greany

Comment: Please don't post external links. Include all related code in your post as formatted text.

Comment: And does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-in-python)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.