# TypeError: Cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType Object. I am getting this error but I am certainly returning something

Tags: python, function, return, typeerror

I have a function call that is supposed to return two ints. However, I am getting a TypeError. I have searched on StackOverflow for other NoneType errors and it seems like people usually forget to return something. However, I am clearly returning something.

```
def userInput():
    current_savings = 0
    r = .04
    annual_salary = float(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
    cost = 1000000
    down_payment = .25*cost
    semi_raise = .07
    months = 0
    # start value = 0, end value = 10000 (divide by 10000 to get the interest rate), value = the middle (binary search)
    start = 0
    end = 10000
    step = 0
    # Get the required months and steps
    rate, steps = search(start,end,step,annual_salary,current_savings, r,down_payment, semi_raise,months)
    print(f'Best savings rate: {rate}')
    print(f'Steps in binary search: {steps}')



def search(start, end, step, salary, savings, r, required_down, semi, months):
    test_value = (start+end)/2
    original_salary = salary
    while savings <= required_down and months <= 36:
        if months != 0 and months%6 == 0:
            salary *= 1+semi
        savings += (savings*r/12) + (salary/12)*(test_value/10000)
        months+=1
    if required_down - 500 < savings < required_down + 500:
        return test_value, step
    elif savings < required_down:
        # Increase test value and pass start = test_value, end = end, test = (new start+end)/2 and run search again; this means rate of savings is too low
        savings = 0
        months = 0
        search(test_value, end, step + 1, original_salary, savings, r, required_down, semi, months)
    else:
        # Decrease test value
        savings = 0
        months = 0
        search(start, test_value, step + 1, original_salary, savings, r, required_down, semi, months)
    if step >= 25:
        rate = 'n/a'
        steps = 'n/a'
        return rate,steps

userInput()
```

`return test_value, step` this line should return two values back to the userInput function. However, this is where the error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\x\Documents\test.py", line 83, in <module>
    userInput()

  File "C:\Users\x\Documents\test.py", line 56, in userInput
    test_value, step = search(start,end,step,annual_salary,current_savings, r,down_payment, semi_raise,months)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack traceback.

Comment: "`return test_value, step` this line should return two values back to the userInput function." Okay - notice how this code is inside an `if` block? What do you think will happen, if that condition is **not** met?

Comment: @user56700 Hi I added the traceback

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hi I modified the code and I think that scenario is answered now

Comment: I do not know why this question was closed...I had already looked at the other questions. As for this, I am certain I am returning the same types.

Comment: That's still inside another condition. What do you think will happen if *that* condition isn't met, either? More to the point: **did you try** to check what is **actually** happening when the code runs? For example, by using a debugger; or using `print` calls to check which parts of the code are reached, in what order, and what certain variable values are at that point? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. We do not provide a debugging service.

Comment: The question is closed because you are asking "why do I get an error, when I call the function and try to unpack the result, telling me that `None` cannot be unpacked?" and the answer is that the function returns `None` - i.e., the question on its face is clearly not the actual question (or else you would see it as a simple typo). The linked duplicates explain **why** it returns `None`, and also give background information on *how to diagnose such problems*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I certainly did debug (about 20 times), steps evaluates to either 10 or 11 and test_value evaluates to ~2148. Upon this, the debugger enters the if condition and hovers over the return line...but then clicking the step-over button leads to the program continuing and not actually returning.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I will take another look at why this is happening with those discussions.  However, in the debugger window, both of the values being returned are of correct type. The links mention the unpack error resulting from some sort of loop being used, however, I have no intention of any iteration. Therefore, I am still confused as to why a "non-iterable" error is coming up.

Comment: Oh, wait, I looked at it more closely. The problem is that you have recursive calls, and you currently **do not use** the result from those calls. Where the code inside `search` says `search(start, test_value, step + 1, original_salary, savings, r, required_down, semi, months)`, for example, that calls the function again **just like calling any other function**, gets a value back from it (which may or may not be `None`), and then **does nothing with** that result. This is also a common duplicate problem. I will update the duplicate link to match.

Comment: "The links mention the unpack error resulting from some sort of loop being used, however, I have no intention of any iteration." Whenever code says `x, y = ...`, that is iteration over the `...`. Python needs to figure out which elements are in the `...`, in order to assign the first one to `x` and the second one to `y`, and to make sure that there are exactly that many elements. Similarly for more complex examples.

Comment: Please see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854214/523612).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Got it, I just added a return to each recursive call, and it worked. Thanks a lot